# Encountered Expected CSRF token not found error while testing Stormpath

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot, stormpath

I am following the example of Stormpath here:
http://docs.stormpath.com/java/spring-boot-web/http-request-authentication.html

So far everything else has been working.

But when I try to issue the command:

```
curl -X POST --data 'grant_type=password&username=ACCOUNT_USERNAME&password=ACCOUNT_PASSWORD' \
     -H 'Origin: http://localhost:8080' http://localhost:8080/oauth/token
```

I get this error:

```
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="box col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <div class="stormpath-header">
                <img src="https://stormpath.com/images/template/logo-nav.png" />
            </div>
            <div class="logo">
                <h1>403</h1>
            </div>
            <p class="lead text-muted">Expected CSRF token not found. Has your session expired?</p>
            <a href="/" class="btn btn-primary">Go Home</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Any clues on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which Stormpath Spring Boot Starter are you using?

`stormpath-default-spring-boot-starter` (and others) include Spring Security.

At this moment, Spring Security and `/oauth/token` are incompatible with the Stormpath integration.

Good News! We are literally releasing the new Token Management integration this week. It will be release `1.0.RC8.3`. You can track it's status [here](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-sdk-java/milestones/1.0.RC8.3). It integrates perfectly up through the Spring stack, including Spring Security. It also provides both access and refresh tokens and supports exchanging refresh tokens for new access tokens.

If you want the `/oauth/token` endpoint to work in advance of this release, you can either use a different Stormpath Starter or you can disable Spring Security.

For the first approach, you can use the `stormpath-spring-boot-starter`.

For the second approach, add the following lines to your `application.properties` file:

`stormpath.spring.security.enabled = false
security.basic.enabled = false`

Comment: I did not include Spring Security, but as you have mentioned, stormpath already includes the Spring Security. I am using the stormpath-spring-boot-starter. I tried disabling spring security in the application.properties but I got a whole bunch of errors when I start up the server.

Comment: I work for Stormpath. Let's switch over to support@stormpath.com. Please send your pom.xml or build.gradle file. We can do a screen share too, if it will help. I'll post the solution back here as well when we figure out what's going on.

Comment: I also want to point out the the `stormpath-spring-boot-starter` does *not* include Spring Security. `stormpath-default-spring-boot-starter`, `stormpath-spring-security-spring-boot-starter`, and `stormpath-spring-security-webmvc-spring-boot-starter` all *do* include Spring Security.

Comment: I just confirmed that the tutorial you are basing your example on, https://github.com/stormpath/spring-boot-spring-security-tutorial, does require Spring Security. If Spring Security is not a requirement for you, you can easily use one of the tutorials found within the Stormpath SDK project, like this one: https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-sdk-java/tree/master/tutorials/spring-boot/00-the-basics. The /oauth/token endpoint will work as expected in that tutorial.

Comment: I just wanted to point out that in this particular case, disabling csrf would not help. When we release the 1.0.RC8.3 this week, you will be able to use the /oauth/token endpoint and Spring Security together.